# Best methods in python to perform Multi Sequence Alignment (MSA) with categories - not letters?

Tags: python, alignment, sequence

I was looking for **methods in python to perform MSA (multi sequence alignment) on categories (word-level)**

In bioinformatics, methods for arranging the primary sequences of DNA, RNA, or protein involve sequences with letters and of the same length.

Whereas what I want to achieve is to align multiple sequences (of different length) of classes like "cat", "dog" "bird".

Input example :

```
sequence 1: " cat - dog - dog - bird - dolphin "
sequence 2: " dog - dog - bird "
sequence 3: " dog - dolphin - bird - dolphin "
```

Output example :

```
aligned sequence = " NONE - dog - dog -bird - dolphin "
```

Do you know some good methods I could try for my problem ? Thank you !

Comment: up! up ! up ! up !

Answer (score 0):

Encode the labels as letters, say "cat" is "A", "dog" is "B", and so on. Convert source sequences as strings of those letters, e.g. "ABCE", "BCDE", etc. Then use MSA algos on those strings and backtrack to original labels.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. I thought about this but the problem is that I have more than 300 classes, and there is not enough alphabetical letters/characters to encode my labels. Any suggestions ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a utf-16 encoding for the strings, That should give you large enough alphabet. hopefully there is an MSA implementation that is generic enough to handle such strings.